# Do karma and your choices really change the way Fallout 3 is played?

Tags: fallout-3

In my last playthrough I always had good karma and didn't do evil things. I'm not sure if it's worth to play again just to be really evil.

Do karma and your choices really change the way playing this game?

Comment: Asking us if something is worth playing again is an extremely opinionated question.  There's nothing objective we can use to answer the question.  If you can re-word this to just focus on whether or not the choices you make in-game have an effect, we might have something we can answer here.

Comment: Well, i just wanted to know if choices really matter and if the story is different if you act different.

Comment: I'd recommend re-wording your question to ask that, then.  Asking if something is worth playing hits the close reason rather well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you play Fallout 3 for its story and characters, it sure is worth playing again. Many quests have different outcomes relative to your choices, and your relation to other characters will not be the same if you are evil.

And you can do fun things in Megaton, one of the first towns of the game :D

Comment: Megaton definetly has a very differant approach for an evil character, but many guides often note that there is far less content associated with the evil outcome.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on what kind of player you are, as -- although there is lots of new/different stuff -- there is a lot of things you already know that will be boring the second time.  So the real question is:

"*Should I give a second playthrough a try?"*

and the answer here is:

Absolutely yes!

I did it for myself and it was a lot of fun playing evil, but after a while I was bored and gave up. But it was worth it. Don't just try to push yourself through it when you start finding it boring because other people told you it will be good. When it starts getting boring, it won't get anymore exciting after playing a bit longer.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.

It's such a large game that unless you've played it through multiple times or REALLY thoroughly on a single playthrough, there will be something you've missed. The game will feel completely different as well depending on your morality, with the way NPCs treat you and the options available to you (like companions or quest outcomes).

In games I typically play as the saint and try to be the nicest guy I can, but in Fallout 3 I found that I had more fun being evil instead. For playthrough 2 at least. ;)